# Fit image in a imageview to fill screen and enabling horizontal scroll if needed maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

im trying to achieve a imageview as shown in image. Also the constrain i have is to fill the screen's height with image which loads from cloud[either scale up or scale down] and enable a horizontal scroll maintaining the aspect ratio. **I do not want vertical scroll at all in any case.**
Please find image below for reference.![image: Reference image]

Comment: you want both vertical and horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @PsyDuck nope as mentioned in the question i need only horizontal scrolling [sorry if i have not explained well,il update Q]..

Comment: OK. So what is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: I tried different implementations to achevie this but i dint acheive..One thing that came close to what i need is this https://github.com/Egorand/android-scrollable-imageview

Comment: But the above library has both horizontal and vertical scrolling.. what i need is the vertical scroll should be removed.. im new to android layouts..

Comment: Override that library. Remove  `private int getMaxVertical(){return (getDrawable().getBounds().height()-screenH);}` from the class `ScrollableImageView.java`

Comment: Just use HorizontalScrolView with one child View: ImageView, make sure to set adjustViewBounds to true

Comment: @elixirbash what's the status?